# Ruby alternative to fabric

Tags: python, ruby

Is there a Ruby alternative to Python based [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)?

Comment: google 'ruby ssh wrapper'?

Comment: Really now, *do not* migrate software recommendations to SO! They are off topic.

Comment: I believe this should be a Unix/Linux question, not a SO question.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Unix/Linux, but cannot go to SO for the reason Braiam stated. softwarerec would likely be the most appropriate home.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a software recommendation and has nothing to do w/ Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing I can see is [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/capistrano-pure-ruby/).

With `fabric`:

```
from fabric.api import run

def uptime():
    run('uptime')
```

then:

```
fab -H localhost uptime
```

With `Capistrano`:

```
task :uptime, :hosts => "localhost" do
  run "uptime"
end
```

then:

```
cap uptime
```